# How to read .bwt file .sa file?

Tags: sequence-alignment, bwa

In BWA project in bwt.c file I found bwt_dump_bwt method and bwt_dump_sa method. I want to use them to read .bwt file and .sa file. I wrote the following program:

```
int main(void)
{
  char *tmp, *prefix;
    bwt_t *bwt;
    prefix = bwa_idx_infer_prefix("hg19bwaidx");

    tmp = calloc(strlen(prefix) + 5, 1);
    strcat(strcpy(tmp, prefix), ".bwt");
    bwt = bwt_restore_bwt(tmp);

  return 0;
}
```

I got the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_bwa_idx_infer_prefix", referenced from:
      _main in readbwt-3022ec.o
  "_bwt_restore_bwt", referenced from:
      _main in readbwt-3022ec.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any help ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the bwa source code, file bwt.{c,h} implement basic operations on .bwt and .sa files. They depend on utils.{c,h}, but you can create a fake utils.h to cut this dependency as is shown below. Then you only need three files: kvec.h, bwt.h and bwt.c to access .bwt and .sa.

The following example demonstrates how to find super-maximal exact matches (SMEMs). Note that internally bwa concatenates all database sequences into one long string. If you use bwt.{c,h} only, you get coordinates on this long string but not on each chromosome. You have to call APIs in bntseq.{c,h}, which are fairly independent, too. You can go on to implement a mini bwa-mem with [this example](https://github.com/lh3/bwa/blob/master/example.c), but you will need all the bwa-mem source code, except the main function.

### Compiling and running

```sh
# compile the example
git clone https://github.com/lh3/bwa
mkdir -p tiny-smem && cd tiny-smem
cp ../bwa/{bwt.c,bwt.h,kvec.h} .              # you need at least these three files
### then create utils.h and test.c shown below ###
gcc -g -O2 -Wall bwt.c test.c -o tiny-smem    # compile tiny-smem

# create a bwa index if you don't have it. We use chr20 from GRCh38 as an example:
(cd ../bwa && make)                           # compile bwa for indexing
../bwa/bwa index -p chr20 path/to/human/chr20.fa

# run the example
./tiny-smem chr20.bwt chr20.sa TTTTCTTCTTTTGTAATATAAGCATTgGTTGTTCTAAATTTCTCTCTTGGCACTGCTTTA
```

The last command line above outputs:

```
0       0       26      1       -125734
0       14      27      4       -3657204        +16021887       +11802682       +54692983
0       15      29      1       +8344885
0       17      31      1       -39545379
0       19      37      1       +55060482
0       25      39      2       +1198672        -26409692
0       27      60      1       -125700
```

where column 2 and 3 give the coordinate of SMEM on the query, col4 the number of exact hits and the following columns are the list of hits in the concatenated coordinate.

### File: utils.h

```c
#ifndef FAKE_UTILS_H
#define FAKE_UTILS_H

#define xassert(cond, msg) assert(cond)
#define xopen(fn, mode) fopen((fn), (mode))
#define err_fclose(fp) fclose(fp)
#define err_fread_noeof(ptr, size, n, fp) fread((ptr), (size), (n), (fp))
#define err_fwrite(ptr, size, n, fp) fwrite((ptr), (size), (n), (fp))
#define err_fflush(fp) fflush(fp)
#define err_fseek(fp, off, whence) fseek((fp), (off), (whence))
#define err_ftell(fp) ftell(fp)

#endif // ~FAKE_UTILS_H
```

### File: test.c

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "bwt.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  bwt_t *bwt;
  int j, max_intv = 100; // ignore SA intervals larger than this value
  bwtintv_v r = {0,0,0};

  if (argc < 4) { fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./test <.bwt> <.sa> <seq>\n"); return 1; }
  if ((bwt = bwt_restore_bwt(argv[1])) == NULL) abort(); // read .bwt
  bwt_restore_sa(argv[2], bwt);                          // read .sa
  for (j = 3; j < argc; ++j) {
    int i, k, x, len = strlen(argv[j]);
    uint8_t *seq = (uint8_t*)malloc(len);
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) { // convert A/C/G/T/N => 0/1/2/3/4
      int c = tolower(argv[j][i]);
      if (c == 'a') seq[i] = 0;
      else if (c == 'c') seq[i] = 1;
      else if (c == 'g') seq[i] = 2;
      else if (c == 't') seq[i] = 3;
      else seq[i] = 4;
    }
    x = 0, r.n = 0;
    while (x < len) {
      x = bwt_smem1(bwt, len, seq, x, 1, &r, 0); // find SMEMs
      for (k = 0; k < r.n; ++k) { // traverse each SMEM
        bwtintv_t *p = &r.a[k]; // p->info encodes start and end on the query
        printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t%d", j-3, (int)(p->info>>32), (int)p->info, (int)p->x[2]);
        if (r.a[k].x[2] <= max_intv) { // don't retrieve coordinates for huge intervals
          int l_mem = (int)p->info - (int)(p->info>>32);
          for (i = 0; i < p->x[2]; ++i) { // traverse each hit
            uint64_t y = bwt_sa(bwt, p->x[0] + i); // get suffix array coordinate
            if (y < bwt->seq_len>>1) printf("\t+%ld", (long)y);
            else printf("\t-%ld", (long)(bwt->seq_len - y - l_mem));
          }
        }
        putchar('\n');
      }
    }
    free(seq);
  }
  free(r.a);
  bwt_destroy(bwt);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to include `bwa.o` in your call to `clang`, since it holds the definitions of those functions. This will cause a good number of object files, so you might as well just `clang -o foo *.o foo.c -lz -lpthread -lm -lrt` and get it over with. Since this was quite obviously never meant to be done, you'll have to remove at least one `main()` function from `bwa.c`.

Note that further questions regarding this will be considered off-topic and closed, since it's purely about compiling something that you want to write yourself.

Comment: Thanks. But there is no main() in bwa.c by the way I want to do something ppl did before. like this call to bwt_dump_bwt in this link: https://github.com/nsoranzo/bwa/blob/master/bwtindex.c The problem is I'm new to c programming. That why I need a help and still I can't understand how to do it.

Comment: There's a main in a different file then. You linked to a fork of the bwa repository, which apparently used to include that file.

Comment: I ran clang -o main bwa.o main.c -lz -lpthread -lm -lrt and I got: ld: library not found for -lrt and when I removed  -lrt I got many other errors. Any idea? I'm a Mac user maybe this is the problem.

Comment: You'll have to figure out the equivalent library (or install it) on OS X, or whatever system you're using.

Comment: I ran BWA successfully on my system. But I can't read .bwt with the program that I wrote.